# how to update combobox in laravel?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel-5.8

I want to update the combobox, but when i run the program the error appears. the error said

> Undefined variable: jenis (View: D:\laravel\makanan\resources\views\edit_upload.blade.php)

what is the solution and what sintax to use ?

this is sintax in the controller:

```
public function prosesedit($id, Request $request)
    {
        $makan = Gambar::find($id);
        $nama_file = $makan->file;
        $jenis = JenisMkn::select('id_jenis','jenis_makanan')->get();


        if($request->hasfile('file'))
        {
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $nama_file = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $tujuan_upload = 'image_file';
            $file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);
        }

        $makan->update([
            'file'=>$nama_file,
            'nama_makanan'=>$request->makan,
            'kode_makanan'=>$request->jenis,
        ]);
        return redirect(route('makan'));
    }
```

and this is html

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <b>Jenis Makanan</b>
                    <br/>
                    <select name="jenis" id="" class="form control input-sm">
                        @foreach ($jenis as $j)
                            <option value="{{$j->id_jenis}}">{{$j->jenis_makanan}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
```

help me please

Comment: Show us the code where you use the blade view.

Answer (score 0):

In Your edit function where you return the edit_upload.blade.php,with this return please pass the variable jenis like

```
return view('edit_upload',compact('jenis'));
```